# Flying with someone else's children

Tags: air-travel, usa, california

I am looking to take two of my nephews (12 and 10) on their first flight.

The flight will be about 1 hour long and will stay within the state.

Do I need some kind of written consent from their parents (my brother)?

Also, would they even need some kind of ID?

Comment: maybe saying which state will help as some rules depend on the state (not sure though)

Comment: Which airline might make a difference too.

Comment: Most likely JetBlue, Virgin, or Southwest

Comment: Written consent is always a good idea when traveling with kids that are not your own, no matter what the means of transport.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding ID: they do not need id. Source: [TSA Blog](http://blog.tsa.gov/2010/06/traveling-with-kids.html)

Regarding written consent: It is definitely a good idea but is not a strict requirement any more than if you were driving. Nobody would ask unless one of the kids tries to make a huge scene, yelling "you're not my parent", etc.

International travel would be a different matter.

Comment: I would carry a letter from a parent just as a safety measure in case anything unusual happened. As the others have said, you should not have trouble at TSA and if you are all on one reservation, then you are not dealing with the unaccompanied minor situation, so the airline should not care at all.